# How do I tell Nginx to pass requests to different apps based on the incoming url?

Tags: linux, nginx

How do I tell Nginx to pass requests to different apps based on the incoming url?

For example, mybudgetapp.com and myshoppingapp.com both point to my server where both apps (8001, 8002) and Nginx (80) are running. When a user goes to mybudgetapp.com they should get a response from the app running on 8001. When a user goes to myshoppingapp.com they should get a response from the app running on 8002.

Here is an example that is close to what I want:

```
location / {
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}
```

I have been reading this documentation but the terminology is throwing me off.
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html

Is Nginx the right tool for this, or would Apache be a better fit?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want two apps on the same domain, but say in different directories? example.com/shopping and example.com/budget ? If so they the answer below is incorrect, but I'd need to know exactly what you want to achieve before I can suggest another option.

Comment: @Tim, I edited my question to try to clarify this. Thank you for asking. In this particular case I want them to be separate apps addressed by separate domains, although they are running on the same server.

Comment: Ok then, different domains. The answer below is the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Apache won't be better, however it can do the same work exactly.
The canonical way of fullfilling your wish is to create different `servers` in nginx, and proxy to different backends according to the `Host` *HTTP header*, along with passing that header, if necessary:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myshoppingapp.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://firstapp;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mybudgetapp.com;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://secondapp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there somewhere else that defines http://firstapp and http://secondapp? Or is that where you would put http://localhost:8001 http://localhost:8002?

Comment: you can pull them in `upstream` clause (if you have many backends). Or you can put them in `proxy_pass` directly. Did you try to read the docs ? I take $100/hr for reading docs on behalf of the user.

Comment: Apologies, although I was at a point where I would call that a reasonable price. Hopefully this will be my only excursion into server administration. Thank you for your clear answer.